# Asp.net Cant Post Value to Controller

Tags: asp.net, post

**I want to post email and password to Another Controller's action (to Create )
But values are not posted. When i look at the User1Controller's its writing values are Null like in the screenshot. Please help I'm stuck with this hours and cant understand**

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vkBN.png)

My User1.cs

```
     public partial class Users1
{
    public string userEmail { get; set; }
    public string userPassword { get; set; }
}
```

My User1Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "userEmail,userPassword")] Users1 baska)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users1.Add(baska);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }
```

My Login.cshtml file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Users1",FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="custom-login-panel">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <img class="profile-img" src="~/images/userlogo.svg"
                     alt="">
                <div class="form-login">
                    <h4 style="color:white;">Giriş ve Kayıt Ekranı</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.user1.userEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" ,placeholder="Email" } })
                        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user1.userEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.user1.userPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Passwordd" } })
                        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user1.userPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="group-btn">
                                <input style="width:40%;" type="submit" value="Giriş" class="submit btn btn-primary">
                                <input style="width:40%;" type="submit" value="Kayıt Ol" class="submit btn btn-primary">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your Login.cshtml:

```
you should declare your model.
```

On your httpget action:
    you should declare a new instance of your Users1 class and pass it like a    parameter to your return() method.

On your httppost action:
    You should receive the model as parameter.

I guess that with these changes, it would work.

Comment: I already have declared the model. its still the same. But now I change the code and move the view in Users1Controller now its same controller and works. But  I dont get it why I cant do with this